# Remove contents from a branch which are there in another branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, diff

I am working on a project where I have a git branch, say `A` and there's another branch `B` (A contains all the content of B plus some extra content), they both are branched out of `master`.

Now what I need to do is create a third branch which should contain the difference of these two branches, i.e. `A-B`, basically only the content which is there in branch A and not in B.

I looked for possible solutions and most of them were pointing towards adding specific commits to a new branch, but in my case that would not work since some of the commits also affected the code I want to separate now. The solution that I have built up in my mind points that I should probably take a diff of A and B, then apply the patch on a checkout from master.

Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? As far as I know - there is not feature in git for this. You have to write your own script that you can rerun every time either source branch changes.

Answer (score 2):

With a diagram :

```
*--*--*--* <- master
    \
     a--b--c <- A
            \
             d--e--f <- B
```

---

If your intention is to have `d--e--f` (and only those 3 commits) on top of `master`, you can use `git rebase` :

```
# from branch B :
git checkout B

# create a temporary branch :
git checkout -b onlyB

# use rebase with that temporary branch :
git rebase --onto master A onlyB
```

This should lead you to this result :

```
*--*--*--* <- master
    \     \
     \     d'--e'--f' <- onlyB
      \
       a--b--c <- A
              \
               d--e--f <- B
```

`d'--e'--f'` should contain the same changes as `d--e--f`.

Comment: Nice but why are the first two commands necessary?

Comment: @konsolebox : they aren't :) I think it is more convenient to still have your original branch in case things get too complicated with the rebase operation, but you can also directly rebase branch `B` : `git rebase --onto master A B`